# Is P/poly known to be in RE?

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity, complexity-classes

Is P/poly known to be in RE?
If yes what other classes is it known to be part of.

Answer (score 5):

$P/poly$ is NOT a subset of $RE$. Specifically, the unary non-halting problem (i.e. given a Turing Machine encoded in unary, does it run forever?) is in $P/poly$ but not $RE$. In fact, [every undecidable unary language is in $P/poly$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P/poly).

Comment: The standard halting problem is in RE (unless you are talking about the $\Pi_2$ complete problem of halting on all inputs). Of course any unary encoding of a language outside $RE$ will do.

Comment: @Ariel You're right, fixed!